# How do you move a profile from Chrome Canary to Chrome stable on Windows 10 (1909)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, google-chrome-canary

I currently have another profile/user in Chrome Canary and I now want to switch to stable. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

1) create new profile in Chrome Stable

2) copy contents of profile (may be "Default" or "Profile N" (whatever you want to copy it to, you may have many profiles but N here means number) for example in C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\ChromeSXS\User Data\PROFILE to C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\PROFILE

3) and click on replace file when the popup comes up

:)